# Должно ли ObjectDTO содержать поле ID из ObjectEntity в RestFull приложении?

Tags: java, rest, entity, dto

столкнулся с тем, что во многих статьях классы Entity и классы для отображения в rest DTO отличаются наличием поля Id в последнем.

```
@Data
public class PostDTO {
    String description;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String description;
}
```

В таком случае мы же не сможем передать на вызывающую сторону id поста после, например, сохранения и в дальнейшем не будем знать по какому id искать запись.

И собственно вопрос, - это обязательное правило, что DTO не должно содержать поля id, или оно его содержать может?

Comment: `это обязательное правило, что DTO не должно содержать поля id, или оно его содержать может?` откуда это?

Comment: Поскольку такие объекты не сохраняются в бд, то зачем им ид из бд?

Comment: @RomanC но как тогда допустим из фронта вызвать метод update? передать id в виде параметра запроса? а как фронт узнает к какому объекту в БД нужно обратиться?

Comment: @pra_soul_owl Во первых, у фронта нету такого метода, во вторых фронт никакого представления о бд не имеет.

Comment: Roman C, тогда для чего нужны классы dto и как их использовать ?